# How to loop array with specific html div tag

Tags: php, html, foreach

I have some array like this :

```
array(6) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) 
        { 
            ["menu_image"]=> string(17) "1b5df-menu_16.jpg" 
        } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#23 (1) 
        { 
            ["menu_image"]=> string(18) "2fe75-menu_17.jpeg" 
        } 
[2]=> object(stdClass)#24 (1) 
        { 
            ["menu_image"]=> string(16) "5ceda-menu_8.jpg" 
        } 
[3]=> object(stdClass)#25 (1) 
        { 
            ["menu_image"]=> string(17) "16079-menu_15.jpg" 
        } 
[4]=> object(stdClass)#26 (1) 
        { 
            ["menu_image"]=> string(17) "70c66-menu_13.jpg" 
        } 
[5]=> object(stdClass)#27 (1) 
        { 
            ["menu_image"]=> NULL 
        } 
}
```

I want to show that array in my html page with `div` tag and I still confuse how to loop it with specific `div` tag I want.

I want to show that array in my html and this is the format what I want :

```
<div class="row">
   <img src="menu_image">
   <img src="menu_image">
   <img src="menu_image">
</div>
<div class="row">
   <img src="menu_image">
   <img src="menu_image">
   <img src="menu_image">
</div>
```

How could I make `foreach` looping so that I can get that `div` format ? Thanks

Comment: So you want to group every 3 images in a `<div>`?

Comment: @Sean Yes, you're right

Comment: try my generic answer @Antonio

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (array_chunk($array, 3) as $objs) {
    echo "<div class=\"row\">\n";
    foreach ($objs as $obj) {
        echo "    <img src=\"$obj->menu_image\">\n";
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="1b5df-menu_16.jpg">
    <img src="2fe75-menu_17.jpeg">
    <img src="5ceda-menu_8.jpg">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <img src="16079-menu_15.jpg">
    <img src="70c66-menu_13.jpg">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

This answer uses [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split your array into blocks of 3 e.g.

From this:

```
array(6) {
    [0] => object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(17) "1b5df-menu_16.jpg" }
    [1] => object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(18) "2fe75-menu_17.jpeg" }
    [2] => object(stdClass)#24 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(16) "5ceda-menu_8.jpg" }
    [3] => object(stdClass)#25 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(17) "16079-menu_15.jpg" }
    [4] => object(stdClass)#26 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(17) "70c66-menu_13.jpg" }
    [5] => object(stdClass)#27 (1) { ["menu_image"] => NULL } 
}
```

To this:

```
array(6) {
    [0] => [
        [0] => object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(17) "1b5df-menu_16.jpg" }
        [1] => object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(18) "2fe75-menu_17.jpeg" }
        [2] => object(stdClass)#24 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(16) "5ceda-menu_8.jpg" }
    ]
    [1] => [
        [0] => object(stdClass)#25 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(17) "16079-menu_15.jpg" }
        [1] => object(stdClass)#26 (1) { ["menu_image"] => string(17) "70c66-menu_13.jpg" }
        [2] => object(stdClass)#27 (1) { ["menu_image"] => NULL }
    ]
}
```

Because each each image src is contained in an object, you have to use object notation instead of array notation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the array_chunk function.

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($array, 3) as $chunk): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($chunk as $image): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image->menu_image ?>">
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code just use foreach to loop through the menu_image.

```
<?php
$arrayName = array();
$arrayName[] = array(
    "menu_image" => "2fe75-menu_17.jpeg"
);
$arrayName[] = array(
    "menu_image" => "2fe75-menu_18.jpeg"
);
$arrayName[] = array(
    "menu_image" => "2fe75-menu_19.jpeg"
);

echo '<div class="row">';
foreach($arrayName as $key => $value){
    echo '<img src='."$value[menu_image]".'>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the generic method like this . it will work if you have more than 6 image too .

```
        $i=0;
        $last_img = end($new);

        foreach($new as $key=>$row)
       {
            if($i==0)
             {
               echo '<div class="row">';
             }

             echo '<img src="'.$row->menu_image .'">';

             if($i==2 || $key==$last_img)
             {
                 echo '</div>';
                 $i=-1; //reset the i again -1 because ++ below so -1 
             }

            $i++;
       }  

       ?>
```